# Mixing javascript with c# code with deep nesting. Trying to make external file

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc-4

I have some javascript and c# code inside one of my views that is deeply nested. Heres the general structure something like this:

```
@if(something)
{
    <script type="text/javascript">
          @if(something_else)
          {  
                <text>
                    ...some javascript...
                    event: function(){
                       @ViewBag.Property = value;
                    }
                    ...some more javascript... 
                </text>
          }
          @else if(something_else_else)
          {
                 ...some more javascript...
          }
    <script>
}
```

It works fine in the html file but I would like to put it in an external js file and instead just load like this:

```
@if(something)
{
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~Scripts/thescript.js")"></script>
}
```

However if I try to do this I get error:  `missing } in XML expression`

I tried wrapping the contents in   but it still complains with same error.
Anybody know if this is possible because its a rather long script and making my view very convoluted.

Comment: See Eric's answer. Use partial views instead of js file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you're putting code that includes Razor markup in an external .JS file.

The Razor view engine does not parse content in .JS files, so it would not work as you describe.

However, you can greatly clean up your code by using [Partial Views](http://rachelappel.com/razor/partial-views-in-asp-net-mvc-3-w-the-razor-view-engine/) where repetitive Razor markup occurs in your view.

Comment: Ah, yes I dont know how I overlooked to use a partialview. It worked only when wrapped in text blocks like such: <text>@Html.Partial("_PartialView", null)</text>

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You can use @Html.RazorJSInclude("scriptSource").
Please see the following link

http://djsolid.net/blog/razorjs---write-razor-inside-your-javascript-files